# TCL : why expr not evaluating the following expression

Tags: tcl

Can anyone explain the following:

```
% set a " 1 2"
 1 2
% expr 0x[join $a ""]
invalid bareword "0x12"
in expression "0x12";
should be "$0x12" or "{0x12}" or "0x12(...)" or ...
%
```

Comment: can't reproduce your issue. worked fine for me and gave correct output as `18`

Comment: What exact version of Tcl are you using? `info patchlevel` will say…

Comment: For the record, I've just tried with 8.4, 8.5 and 8.6 and they _all_ work identically (and correctly).

Comment: Note that the error can be reproduced by using a capital letter O in place of the digit 0.

Comment: working fine in Tcl8.5

Comment: @glennjackman i guess you got it correct.. :)